# deserializing XML to object, wrong values

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have created such classes:

```
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Control", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2011/storyboarding/stencilDocument"),Serializable]
    public class ControlStencilXML
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ReferenceName")]
        public string ReferenceName;
        [XmlAttribute("DisplayName")]
        public string DisplayName;
        [XmlAttribute("Revision")]
        public int Revision;
        [XmlAttribute("IsBackground")]
        public bool IsBackground;
        [XmlAttribute("DefaultInsertionPoint")]
        public string DefaultInsertionPoint;
        [XmlAttribute("IsAnimated")]
        public bool IsAnimated;
        [XmlAttribute("KeyWords")]
        public string KeyWords;
        [XmlAttribute("ToolTip")]
        public string ToolTip;
        [XmlElement("ShapeLayouts")]
        public List<ShapeLayout> ShapeLayouts;
    }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ShapeLayout", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2011/storyboarding/stencilDocument")]
public class ShapeLayout
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    string Name;
    [XmlAttribute("HorizontalAlignment")]
    string HorizontalAlignment;
    [XmlAttribute("VerticalAlignment")]
    string VerticalAlignment;
}
```

XLM that I want to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Control ReferenceName="System.Storyboarding.Common.CheckBoxChecked" DisplayName="Checkbox (checked)" ToolTip="Checked checkbox with a text label" Revision="1" IsBackground="false" DefaultInsertionPoint="Default" Keywords="Toggle, Phone" IsAnimated="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2011/storyboarding/stencilDocument">
  <ShapeLayouts>
    <ShapeLayout Name="Check" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <ShapeLayout Name="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <ShapeLayout Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </ShapeLayouts>
</Control>
```

There is no errors when I am trying to deserialize, the problem is that I am getting only first ShapeLayout object, and all of its values are equal to null. Where did I make mistake? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need one more wrapper object to conform to the provided `XML` -

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ShapeLayouts", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2011/storyboarding/stencilDocument")]
public class ShapeLayouts
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShapeLayout", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2011/storyboarding/stencilDocument")]
    public List<ShapeLayout> ShapeLayout { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, working. I've changed also visibilty of  ShapeLayout fields to public.